# Vuejs scoped & unscoped CSS in the same .vue file

Tags: css, vue.js

I'd like to have scoped style & unscoped style in the same `.vue` file at the same time. The reason is because I have some component specific style that I want to be scoped, but also some vue-boostrap custom style that I'd like to apply, but because the elements are in another component (the vue-bootstrap one), if I scope this style it won't work. However, this custom bootstrap styles are specific to this component, so I'd like to have the CSS written in this same file, to avoid files hell.

So I'd like to have `<style lang="scss">` and `<style lang="scss" scoped>` at the same time. But when I do, it only takes the scoped one. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can load scss files in your script part of your Vue component

### typescript

`import "@/path/to/style.scss"`

### javascript

`require("@/path/to/style.scss")`

that way you can have load multiple style sheets into your component at once.